# Why do I appear as one of my own contacts in Gchat, twice?

Tags: apps

I appear twice as a contact in [Gchat](http://gchatapp.com/).  I'm not sure if I am suppose to be there at all, let alone twice.  I do not appear as my own contact in the GMail webpage.

There isn't any way to delete contact in Gchat, so I am not sure how to get rid of these contact entries.

As at least [one of the authors](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/35/juliana-pena) comes to this forum, I thought this would be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pair ([136](https://github.com/lhchavez/gtalkchat/issues/136) and [137](https://github.com/lhchavez/gtalkchat/issues/137)) of known issues in Gchat and we're looking into fixing them. A workaround for now is to hide a contact from the "online" list by tapping and holding the contact and selecting "hide contact" from the context menu. That way, the contact won't appear in the "online" list, though it will appear in the "all" list.

If you find any more bugs in Gchat, let us know by filing a bug in Github or emailing support@gchatapp.com